# Coloring a Shapefile Polygons in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gis, matlab-figure, shapefile

I've imported into matlab the shapefile of the country, and its states: It has the following structure:

```
S=
354x1 struct array with fields:
    Geometry
    BoundingBox
    X
    Y
    ID_0
    ISO
    NAME_0
    ID_1
    NAME_1
    ID_2
    NAME_2
    VARNAME_2
    NL_NAME_2
    HASC_2
    CC_2
    TYPE_2
    ENGTYPE_2
    VALIDFR_2
    VALIDTO_2
    REMARKS_2
    Shape_Leng
    Shape_Area
```

State names are stored in the NAME_2 field, and the coordinates (lat/long) of the boundaries are stored in X and Y. So, there's a value associated to each state which I need to assign graphically to each one of them as a color, just like the picture below. Any ideas how to do this?

[image: Sample Picture]

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty straightforward in ArcGis, QGis. It might be unclear to you.

Comment: Use `fill` to fill 2D polygon shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's the answer. (Maybe the "*This-is-an-unclear-question*" people should refrain from commenting, b/c on average they rarely provide any help, as in this post. Thx!:)

1) Open the shapefile

```
filename = 'C:\...FILESHAPEFILE.shp';
S = shaperead(filename);
lenS = size(S,1);
```

2) Create a color vector with the proper color meaning.

```
Cols = hot(lenS);
```

3) Set the order of the States inside the structure S

```
idxStateOrder = [2 4 3 1];
```

4) Loop over the "States" inside the structure array. Find and remove NaN's so that the fill command works properly.

```
for i = 1 : lenS
    idxState = idxStateOrder(i); % In case the States are not ordered inside S.
    XX = S(idxDept).X;
    YY = S(idxDept).Y;
    idxNan = find(isnan(XX) == 1); XX(idxNan) = []; YY(idxNan) = []; % Find and remove NaNs
    idxNan = find(isnan(YY) == 1); XX(idxNan) = []; YY(idxNan) = []; % Find and remove NaNs
    fill(XX,YY,Cols(i,:))   % This line "paints" each State with the proper color in teh vector Cols.
    hold on
end
```

Done...

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct function available in MATLAB to achieve that task. doc polysplit.

Eg:

```
lat = [45.6 -23.47 78 NaN 43.9 -67.14 90 -89]';
lon = [13 -97.45 165 NaN 0 -114.2 -18 0]';
[latc,lonc] = polysplit(lat,lon)
```